# email check and comma separated check jQuery codes work correctly in separation but not when mixed for disabling the submit button

Tags: html, jquery, form-submit

I have to functions that each of them looks for an email being valid and the other one looks for an input being comma separated (not sure if I have the best comma separated jQuery code).

However, when I write a proper comma separated input in the input box, it still allows me to click on the submit button which is strange because the email is empty and I expect the submit button to stay disabled. Each of these two functions work correctly separately.

```
$("#category_names").on('keyup', function (event) {
    $(".error").hide();
    let hasError = false;

    let isValid = true;
    $('#category_names').each(function() {
        if (($.trim($(this).val()).indexOf(",") == -1)) {
            //alert('Please separate multiple keywords with a comma.');
            $('#commaerror').show();
            hasError = true;
        } else {
            $('#commaerror').hide()
            hasError = false;
        }
    });
    $('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', hasError);


})


$("#email").on('keyup', function() {
    $(".error").hide();
    let hasError = false;

    let emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    let emailAddressVal = $(this).val();
    if (emailAddressVal == '') {
        $("#email").after('<span class="error">Please enter your email address.</span>');
        hasError = true;
    }
    else if (!emailReg.test(emailAddressVal)) {
        $("#email").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid email address.</span>');
        hasError = true;
    }

    $('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', hasError);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check both (all, if there are other inputs as well) conditions are valid in each event handler. It's probably simplest to put all the validation code into a function and call that in the event handler. For example:

```js
function validate() {
  $(".error, #commaerror").hide();
  let hasError = false;

  // validate category names
  $('#category_names').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().indexOf(",") == -1) {
      //alert('Please separate multiple keywords with a comma.');
      $('#commaerror').show();
      hasError = true;
    }
  });
  // validate email
  let emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
  let emailAddressVal = $('#email').val();
  if (emailAddressVal == '') {
    $("#email").after('<span class="error">Please enter your email address.</span>');
    hasError = true;
  } 
  else if (!emailReg.test(emailAddressVal)) {
    $("#email").after('<span class="error">Enter a valid email address.</span>');
    hasError = true;
  }
  
  return hasError;
}

$("#category_names, #email").on('keyup', function(event) {
  $('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', validate());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Enter your email</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control validate purple-border" id="email">
  <br/>
  <label>Enter categories:</label>
  <input type="text" id="category_names" />
  <br/>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple purple-border" disabled="disabled">Perform Frame Classification</button>
```

Note I've cleaned up your `category_names` code a bit, but you need to add further checking so that if there is only one value it still passes, or that something like `abc,` doesn't pass. You might find something like

```
$(this).val().match(/^\s*\w+(\s*,\s*\w+)*\s*$/)
```

more useful.